# Listen to new task or activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, listener, task

Is there any way to receive an event via a broadcast or any other way when new activity starts or any task in android?

Thx 
Mahmoud

Comment: No you can't. You can only recieve events that are broadcasted. Starting an activity or a task and things like that aren't broadcasted intents. That would be a huge security hole

Comment: I understand the security problem but still if I have GET_TASK permission I can go to ActivityManager and check which task recently launched.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do, some profiling or logging or something else?

Well if it's your OWN activities you want to monitor you can just log them when you start them.

If you want to monitor other activities, you could read the logcat periodically and find some strings.

Sorry I can't help you any more...

Comment: I See, but I want to go out of checking loop, it will kill processor, I prefer if I notified

Comment: None of the existing activities will notify anyone of their state. When I said 'periodically' I meant on a timer, like say 5 minutes apart. This won't be real time.